# How to evaluate probability of minimum and maximum of three random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Let $T_A, T_B, T_C$ and $T_M$ are the i.i.d random variables that follows the Exponential distribution Exp(1) i.e. parameter $\lambda = 1$. I want to compute the following
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left(T_M + T_A\right) > \max \left\{T_B,T_C\right\}\right) \mid T_A < \min \left\{T_B,T_C\right\})\mathbb{P}\left(T_A < \min \left\{T_B,T_C\right\}\right)$$

I have tried to evaluate first $\mathbb{P}(T_A < \min \left\{T_B,T_C\right\})$
In this case $$\mathbb{P}(T_A < \min \left\{ T_B, T_C\right\}) \\ \mathbb{P}(T_A <T_B) \mathbb{P}(T_B < T_C)$$

After that I don't know how to proceed as two are random variable. Can some body help

Comment: First of all, $\mathbb{P}(T_A < \min \left\{ T_B, T_C\right\}) =\mathbb{P}(T_A <T_B) \mathbb{P}(T_A < T_C)=1/2 \cdot 1/2=1/4$.

But anyway, I tried to do it somehow nicely, but it all came up only to ugly integration. You can rewrite all in terms of density and compute some double integral. I don't even think that something nice will pop out of it. 

But my guess- it will be slightly more than1/12. Why? because $P(T_M>\{T_B,T_C\}>T_A)=1/(4*3)=1/12$ from symmetry.

Comment: @AlbertParadek Can you post the image of your solution ? and another things why you have multiplied (4*3) How you get 1/12 answer. If you can tell then I will be grateful.